# Use ngrok for accessing remote access on jetson

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, arm64, ngrok, nvidia-jetson

I have a client where I need to do some updates and support on a system running Ubuntu on jetson xavier nx. First I was thinking of using Teamviewer but it is not supporting arm64. The same scenario with google remote desktop and others ...

I tried to use nomachine which works fine when running on the same network. I tried to make it work from outside (from the internet) by running it together with services like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://www.nomachine.com/) but it cant get it to work and I might misunderstand some of the concept. This is what I have done:

1. installed nomachine and ngrok on Jetson
2. run nomachine-service and start the server
3. the server says nx://172.20.10.12 and ssh://172.20.10.12. It runs on port 4000

here comes what I might misunderstand. My idea is to use ngrok to fetch the nomachine so I can access it from a webpage from anywhere instead of running it from my another computer on the same network.

After I saved my accesstoken for ngrok I tried by typing:
./ngrok tcp 172.20.10.12:4000

But it didnt work.

Any idea how I can get this to work, basically to access my jetson from remote

**UPDATE**
I tried this procedure:

1. Create a thunnel: `./ngrok tcp 3389`
2. Go to http://localhost:4040/status  to see the status
   [image]
3. Connecting from client:
   [image]
4. Im asked to login:
   [image: List item]
   But I cannot access. Im using the same login as to ngroks dashboard but Im not getting in.

Shall I use some other login information? Or can I access my login information from ngrok somehwhere?

Answer (score 2):

In your nomachine client running remote, when you add a connection, you'll want to specify the host to be the ngrok hostname and the port to be the ngrok port.

For example, if running `./ngrok tcp 172.20.10.12:4000` starts a tunnel at `4.tcp.ngrok.io:19283`, you'll want to use `4.tcp.ngrok.io` as the host and `19283` as the port, instead of referencing the local address.

Comment: Thanks! I couldnt connect from my client unfortunately. I used the same login as for the ngroks dashboard but failed. See my update above ... Apart from this am I on the right track?

Comment: You need to use your system login, not your ngrok login.  A few other things:  you need to run `ngrok tcp 172.20.10.12:4000`, not `ngrok tcp 3389` since the local NX server is listening on port 4000.  Along with this, you will want to use the NX protocol in step 3 (listed above in your question).  Lastly, make sure the nomachine server is running.